# Connecting C# Back-end with PHP frontend

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, python, web-services

I have a code written in C# I would like to use as the back-end of a site I'm building.
I would prefer not to build the site front-end in ASP.NET (which integrates nicely with C#), and to use PHP or Python instead.

Is that reasonable? Should I re-consider using ASP.NET?
How can I achieve that?

Comment: no problem as far as i know you can code the backend of an application using c# and use php for  frontend

Comment: IIS can handle PHP, but I'm a little confused by your question. ASP.NET and PHP are both server-side. What do you mean by front-end/back-end in this context?

Comment: The frontend for me is where I build the UI of the web-site. The backhand handles the real logic I need (and it is currently written in c#)

Comment: @MemoryOverflow That is a good question. Mostly because I've never used it before. The important things I currently care about are short development time and flexibility. I got the feeling ASP.NET is not the best choice for that.

Comment: @Noam: Your feelings about ASP.NET do not seem to be based on facts then. It is just that you do not have exposure/experience of it and you are scared to venture with it. I would say, give it a try! Build a simple page using PHP & then the same with ASP.NET using Visual Studio. You'll be in a better position to weigh and judge on which path to take. Cheers! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Just use asp.net mvc framework for the frontend instead of plain asp.net. It's easy to learn. And if you know php it will be easy to you undestand asp.net mvc.
I don't see the reasons if you are using c# backend  use php frontend. For sure you can create service layer on c# and communicate with php through it, but it does not make sence for me.

Comment: Can you give a short explanation about MVC and why that should suit me? (I tried wikipedia)

Comment: @Noam: Because you can easy move from php views to asp.net mvc views. Also you can read more about asp.net mvc here (or just search in google) -> http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/14/asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx.

Comment: MVC is a very well established pattern in php world. It is making it over to asp.net late - I have no idea why asp.net didn't just adopt it properly from the start.

Comment: @JohnNicholas: Not only in php, in java also for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do whatever you like. Personally i wouldnt use php because i dont know very much php.

But you can do it, you could expose a soap web service and there are libraries that will let php talk to it.

No one here will be able to tell you what you haven't already told us. Asp.Net will probably be easier because of how everything integrates and you can share classes etc - but that does not mean you HAVE to use it.

Both of them are fairly passive server side technologies that present html to browsers though. why do you need 2 servers?

You have to ask why you are doing it .. if you are playing and want to learn then of course you can do it just to see how it all works. But if you are on a commercial project then id suggest that you dont need both a php and a c# server ... or if you do perhaps you want to go asp.net for your web server and if you need another layer of services behind then use WCF if you want to go a microsoft route. Howver it is usually possible to host all services in the same IIs instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this i have done this for a web site my self use a database server or files,

http://dtpgroup.co.uk/

Your C# application can connection to your store save the info it needs to then php can read them if it file just use a formatted file E.G

if your using Database php can connect to MySQL or MSSQL so your C# application can use MySQL if you know what your doing in C# if not and your more comfortable in php then use MSSQL (also php have the superior documentation )

I work in both frequently

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, in normal instances, reading data with C# writing it to files and loading up with PHP sound slow, inefficient and down wright crazy. I believe these terms are being used wrongly.

Client Server - user machine - database great for private networks where you connect to the DB without going over the internet

vs n-Tier
Client - Browser programming html, css, javascript connects to middleware over the internet
Middleware - inside your firewall, connects browser to database could be called part of backend - php and C# are middleware languages
Database final (generally 3rd) tier

With php and c# you are creating multiple middleware layers

why why why would you do this for a web app pick one

now if you have a web app with PHP and sneakerware in house client server apps that are controlled ie shipping, accounting that are not exposed - maybe but you have added complexity that you would not need (generally)

Gary